# How can I remove tokens with non-alphabetic characters in Python?

Tags: python

I'd like to remove tokens with non-alphabetic characters in one sentence.

**Example:**

Input: `"I like python@ pretty muc*h."`

Output: `"I like pretty"`

Comment: Cool. Did you try anything yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.isalpha`:

```
s = "I like python@ pretty muc*h."
print " ".join([i for i in s.split() if i.isalpha()])
```